# How To Get Yahoo Finance Headlines For Specific Symbol

Tags: javascript, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am using this code to get stock data for one specific symbol but I need to get 
Headlines of this symbol too, so can you please help to figure it out how to list last 5 updated headlines ?

As you know Yahoo displaying the Headlines in return page for each symbol as

[image]

Here is the code I have :

```
<div id="stockTick"></div>

jQuery(document).ready(updateStockPrice);
function updateStockPrice(){
    jQuery.getJSON('https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=DNT.TO&callback=?',function(response){
        var stockInfo = response[0];
        var stockString ='<div class="stockWrapper"><strong>Stock Price:</strong> ';
        stockString +='<span class="stockPrice">CAD. '+stockInfo.l+'</span>';
        stockString +=' <span class="stockChange">'+stockInfo.c+'</span>';
        stockString +='</div>';
        jQuery('#stockTick').html(stockString);
      });
    setTim
```

Thanks